# I want to use 2 dropdown list in a way so that second dropdown list show remaining items of the first dropdown list except the selected one

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to use 2 dropdown list in a way so that second dropdown list show remaining items of the first dropdown list except the selected one.
if u have the solution please send to me at rsolanki2008@gmail.com as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is called "cascading dropdowns" and has lots of solutions online. For example, [this one](http://www.mikepope.com/blog/DisplayBlog.aspx?permalink=1620).